# Understanding SQL Server query execution and transactions

Tags: sql-server, transactions

I'm quite experienced with SQL databases but mostly with Oracle and MySQL.

Now I'm dealing with SQL Server 2012 (Management Studio 2008) and facing a weird behaviour that I cannot explain.

Considering these 3 queries and an origin table made of 400k rows:

```
SELECT ID_TARJETA 
INTO [SGMENTIA_TEMP].[dbo].[borra_borra_] 
FROM [DATAMART_SEGMENTIA].[DESA].[CLIENTES]

ALTER TABLE [SGMENTIA_TEMP].[dbo].[borra_borra_] 
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (ID_TARJETA)

SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM [SGMENTIA_TEMP].[dbo].[borra_borra_]
```

If I run them **one after the other** it runs OK. (total: **~7sec**).

If I select them all and run **all the queries at once** it runs BAD. (total: **~60sec**)

Finally if I wrap it all **with a transaction** it runs OK again

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

SELECT ID_TARJETA 
INTO [SGMENTIA_TEMP].[dbo].[borra_borra_] 
FROM [DATAMART_SEGMENTIA].[DESA].[CLIENTES]

ALTER TABLE [SGMENTIA_TEMP].[dbo].[borra_borra_] 
ADD PRIMARY KEY(ID_TARJETA)

SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM [SGMENTIA_TEMP].[dbo].[borra_borra_]

COMMIT;
```

The whole picture makes no sense to me, considering that creating transactions looks quite expensive the first scenario should be a slow one, and the second one should work far better, am I wrong?

The question is quite important for me since, I'm building programatically (jdbc) this sort of packages of queries and I need a way to tweak its performance.

Comment: Pls check the SET STATISTICS IO and SET STATISTICS TIME in Query Options -> Advanced dialog. Also, review the actual execution plan.

Answer (score 0):

The *only* difference between the two snippet provided, is that the first uses the default transaction mode and the second uses an **Explicit Transaction**.

Since SQL Server default transaction mode is **Autocommit Transactions**, *each individual statement is a transaction*.

You can find more information about transaction modes [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174377%28v=sql.110%29.aspx).

You can try this to see if it run in 60 sec too:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

SELECT ID_TARJETA 
INTO [SGMENTIA_TEMP].[dbo].[borra_borra_] 
FROM [DATAMART_SEGMENTIA].[DESA].[CLIENTES];

COMMIT;

BEGIN TRANSACTION;

ALTER TABLE [SGMENTIA_TEMP].[dbo].[borra_borra_] 
ADD PRIMARY KEY(ID_TARJETA);

COMMIT;

BEGIN TRANSACTION;

SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM [SGMENTIA_TEMP].[dbo].[borra_borra_]

COMMIT;
```

Comment: No question, it is related to transtractions. BUT why if I execute one query after the other (3 transactions) runs really well (7 secs adding their independent times) and if I select +execute them all together (1 transaction?) it runs awfully slow (60secs)?.

Comment: @IvanArrizabalaga handling 3 transactions instead of one seems a good reason to this. Think of executing BEGIN TRANSACTION / COMMIT 3 times instead of 1.